# Google apps script: Check field input empty

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code:

```
  function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
        .setTitle("Show verifica")
        .setHeight(15).setWidth(500)
 var form = app.createFormPanel().setWidth(400).setHeight(30).setTitle("Form Panel
  Search").setVisible(true);
var fPanel = app.createFlowPanel().setId('fPanel').setTitle("Panel search");    

// input search 
 fPanel.add(app.createTextBox().setName('idSearch').setId('idSearch').setWidth(150));
 var clickHandler =
     app.createServerClickHandler("respondToSubmit").addCallbackElement(fPanel);
   fPanel.add(app.createButton("Search", clickHandler).setEnabled(true));
   form.add(fPanel);
app.add(form); 
return app;
 }

 function respondToSubmit() {
 // .... code
  return app;
 }
```

if you do not insert any code and I press enter to search I get the error: "Error  encourentered. An unexpected error occurred"
I want to check "idSearch" blank and press enter to send a message "Enter Code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any error in the code that you have published here, the error seems to be with the code used in the respondToSubmit function, are you usinf any getelementbyID as they generally cause these errors when called for non existent IDs.

Comment: "I dont see any error in the code that you have published here". In fact, you're right it is. if not I post code search and crush the "Enter" I get the error If I enter a search code everything works.
Perhaps as Serge says I have to use a field validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [validators](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/server-handler?hl=en#validateLength%28Widget,Integer,Integer%29) to handle that...

add a validator on the handler with a condition on your textBox content length and it will prevent triggering if the textBox is empty.

You can also get a more userfriendly behavior by adding a warning message shown by a clientHandler that is also validate on textBox length but with an inverted condition so that the message shows up when textBox is empty and you click the button.

There are [dozens of example here on SO using validators, a quick search will guide you.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Dvalidation)

Edit:  note also that the error you mentioned occurs in the handler function but since you don't show it  no one can tell you what is wrong. So even if the validation can prevent the error to happen it would still be preferable to repair your code ...