# google script editor: check if field input is empty

Tags: javascript, validation, input, google-sheets

I'd like to know how to check if an input is empty in a google script.

When I leave an input empty the parameters and log 'e' in the script:

> [17-03-10 08:50:33:669 CET] Logger.log([{parameter={emptyInput=, notEmptyInput=012345}, contextPath=, contentLength=96, queryString=null, parameters={emptyInput=[], notEmptyInput=[012345], =[]}, =}, []]...) [0 seconden]

Might be a duplicate of [Google apps script: Check field input empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653917/google-apps-script-check-field-input-empty) but that second answer is based on *now* deprecated code..

I know I can check in my front end code before sending data to the google script.. but I want to know if this is also possible.

Edit: I'll add that I've tried checking against null, undefined and "". I've also tried `if(!e.parameters.emptyVar)` and `if(e.parameters.emptyVar ==)` (i know..), but nothing seemed to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible example code? Whats e?

Comment: About e: Well I was following this tutorial https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server and e is the content we're sending to the google script.. It contains the input values of a form.

Example code: https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/blob/master/google-apps-script.js and https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/blob/master/index.html for the form.

Comment: The other question is about a deprecated service, UiApp.

Comment: Thank you for that very useful comment.